# Can a Tx landlord demand payment for garage on expired lease?

Tags: united-states, residential-lease, texas

My prior lease expired in February and I signed a new lease. The prior lease included a garage addendum. I was charged separately for the garage the first 2 months, then the charges stopped.

I received notice this week requesting partial payment for garage fees not paid on the prior lease. I don’t have a problem paying but want to make sure I’m not opening the door to any other fees. Am I obligated to pay? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the prior lease (or a separate agreement) included a monthly (or otherwise regular) payment for the garage, that was a legitimate debt and you are obliged to pay it. If the current lease also includes such an additional payment it will have to be paid as agreed. If it does not, then no such payments will be owed in future. If the current lease references the terms of the previous lease, and bases the current terms on the previous terms, that may include a garage payment without specifically mentioning it in the current lease.

Thre question mentions "partial payment". The tenant will be liable for all agreed payments for the garage (and for anything else) under the old lease for its full term,  until it expired, that were not previously paid. Once all such payments have been made there shold be no further payments owing, except whatever was agreed to in the new lease. Those payments will be due as agreed.

Comment: Thanks for the response!

Comment: Once I agree and pay, should this stop any future claims on the old lease, for the garage?

Comment: @Jennifer  I have edited my answer to clarify it on the subject of further payments. If it now seems to you to fully answer your question, you can accept the answer by clicking the check mark beside the answer.  Once you have sufficient reputation, you cna upvote any helpful answers, as well.

Comment: I’m appreciative of your response and apologize but the last response was unclear on one point. My last question. It sounds like you’re saying by agreeing to and paying the amount requested today, they can request more later, as I’m obligated to the full amount, not just what is requested today. Did I understand your update correctly? Thanks

Comment: @Jennifer You were obligated under the original lease to pay the full amounts agreed under that lease.  Paying part of that does not relieve you of the obligation to pay the rest if some remains unpaid. Paying what is now asked neither increases nor reduces your total obligation, it just makes a payment toward the debt. However, you can ask for an agreement that the payment for which you are now billed constitutes the final payment under the old lease. Your landlord is not required to make such an agreement, but might do so. ...

Comment: @Jennifer ... I am assuming that the landlord did not violate his or her obligations under the old lease so as to entitle you not to pay money otherwise owing. If there was such a violation, that would have to be taken into account, but the question and comments do not mention anything of the sort.